# Xcode 6 Submission Error

Tags: ios, xcode, submission

When I try to submit my application in Xcode 6, I get the following error:

ERROR ITMS-90121: “This bundle is invalid. The executable name, as reported by CFBundleExecutable in the info.plist file may not contain these characters: \ [ ] { } parenthesis . + *”

I went and changed the default executable name, ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}, to the apps name. When I did this, I got the following error when I tried to run the app on my phone or a simulator:

“The file “app name” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it.”

And the app will not run on my phone and I can’t submit it. I looked for help on how to help this and all I could find is to change the executable name to ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} for Xcode 6 and it will work.

However, when I do this, I get my original error… It is as if I am stuck in a never ending error circle I can’t get out of. Other things I have tried:

(1) Deleting the derived data in the organizer (2) Restarting Xcode (3) Restarting my computer and phone (4) Keeping the default executable name without the symbols

My app is finished I’m just running into this one error in the submission that I can’t seem to find a way around. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: what is your actual app name? `${EXECUTABLE_NAME}` is just a placeholder for the name that you chose. I would guess, THAT name contains some of the invalid characters.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @luk2302 ! The name of my app was "SAT Prep: Math (Free Version)" So I changed the name of my app and changed the target name to SAT Prep Math Free and it submitted fine. Thanks again!